# Using SonarQube in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I just installed SonarQube in Eclipse, but I don't know how to use it :

[Here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse) It said:
Link projects to Sonar server

What is the server? Should we create another project somewhere else with the same name as the project in Eclipse?

It's really confusing, I will appreciate if someone could help by a small example.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To be able to use Sonar Eclipse, you first need to install a Sonar server 5.1 or older as described here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse

Then, you will have to run a first analysis (out of Eclipse) of your project to have it referenced in the Sonar server. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code

After those 2 steps, then you'll be able to run analyses directly within Eclipse once you have associated your local project with the Sonar server.

UPDATE:
Sonar 5.2+ is no longer supporting sonar eclipse plugin in favor of sonarlint. Unfortunately sonarlint has [no customization options](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html).

> We will make this feature available in upcoming versions, probably by
>   requiring to "connect" SonarLint with an existing SonarQube server
>   instance.

Comment: At the moment I'm not very pleased with codehaus, as this is the third page I've gone to with this question that links to the same set of deleted pages on their wiki.  Apparently we are expected to switch to SonarQube.

Comment: @SonarQubeTeam it isn't at all obvious that you have to run your first analysis "outside of eclipse" to get the eclipse plugin to talk to the SonarQube server.  I don't see this spelled out anywhere except here in your otherwise great documentation.

Comment: By definition, the Eclipse project must be assigned to an SonarQube one. So existence requirement is perfectly intelligible... Else, read [Configuring SonarQube in Eclipse](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) from Confluence User's guide.

Answer (score 5):

Sonar can be run now localy to analyse the java project

for more information visit [sonar eclipse](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-eclipse-2-0/)

- [Eclipse update site](http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse/)
- [Installation guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)
- [Eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonar)

Also you can visit [DZONE](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/static-code-analysis-and) for step by step installation procedure