# SonarQube Eclipse Plugin manual download

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

I want to download SonarQube Eclipse plugin and install on Eclipse IDE manually.(I know it can be download through MarketPlace of Eclipse IDE, but I need to do manually.) Anyone knows where it is possible? Any official site available ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download from Bintray => https://bintray.com/sonarsource/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/_latestVersion
The link is given at [Sonarlint for Eclipse Homepage](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/)

Comment: Thanks Rebse. Is SonarLint a client for SonarQube Server ? Totally equal to sonarQube plugin ?

Comment: @Débora I assumed you want the eclipse plugin for a current version of Sonarqube. Sonarlint is the successor of the old Sonarqube Elipse plugin, it works with Sonarqube 4.5.4+  - Most recent Sonarqube version is 5.6 which is also declared as new LTS version. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7977137/130683

Comment: Then Is this the lates plugin ?   org.sonarlint.eclipse.site-2.1.0.20160603-1122-RELEASE.zip

Comment: @Débora yes, the bintray link from my answer points to the  latest version. Just to let you know => Sonarlint is still lacking some features, but for IMO its already sufficient. See discussions at Sonarlint Google Group to get some impressions => https://groups.google.com/d/forum/sonarlint

Answer (score 9):

1.) Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace... and search for "SonarQube". If you are not finding SonarQube. Follow next steps
Go to Help > Install New Software... This should display the Install dialog box. Paste the Update Site URL (http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/) into the field Work with and press Enter. This should display the list of available plugins and components.
2.) Check the component you wish to install (see Features details).
3.) Click Next. Eclipse will then check to see if there is any issue which would prevent a successful installation.
4.) Click Finish to begin the installation process. 
5.) Once the installation process is finished, Eclipse will ask if you want to restart the IDE. It is strongly recommended that you restart the IDE.

Comment: This example will help to install sonar on eclipse

Answer (score 1):

In my experience SonarLint is **not** equivalent to SonarQube. When not bound to SonarQube it reports many errors we don't care about. Bound to our SonarQube it reported, for example, about 10 errors compared to 303 on our SonarQube. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41167813/2716301)